# Reading a pointer to a string

Tags: c#, strings, .net

What it is doing basically is reading an `std::string` from a given pointer.

I was told that using a `StringBuilder` as I am is not the best way to achieve this, so I would like to know how this would be best written.

As additional information, that is a pointer of a `std::string` and I've made that because I was originally curious if there was a way to read a `std::string` in C# without having to create a bridge using C++/CLI.

How could I optimize this bit of code for best performance?

```
public static string ReadStdString(IntPtr address)
{
    var capacity = Marshal.ReadInt32(address + 24);
    var length = Marshal.ReadInt32(address + 20);
    var startStr = address + 4;
    if (capacity > 15)
        startStr = (IntPtr)Marshal.ReadInt32(address + 4);

    var result = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        result.Append((char)Marshal.ReadByte(startStr, i));
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep referring to "std::string"?  Do you mean that `address` is supposed to be a C-style string?  A null-terminated array of characters?

Comment: @nhgrif yes, I have a c++ dll and from a function from it I get returned a Entity within this Entity structure I have a std::string property, however in c# you cant read a std::string with conventional ways

Comment: How long is the string?

Comment: @Mat'sMug could be empty or as big as 50 chars I don't think it can exceed 50 chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> var result = new StringBuilder();
> for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
> {
>     result.Append((char)Marshal.ReadByte(startStr, i));
> }
> ```

You're working in a tight loop: a `StringBuilder` looks like a reasonable tool to use.

One thing I would change that could impact performance (depending on the length of the string involved), is the `StringBuilder` constructor being used:

```
var result = new StringBuilder(length);
```

There's no reason *not* to specify the length of the string you're building if you know it from the start; that will reduce the overhead, since the internals of the builder won't need to manage growth.

---

The loop is a one-liner. You have this one-liner just a few instructions above:

> ```
> if (capacity > 15)
>     startStr = (IntPtr)Marshal.ReadInt32(address + 4);
> ```

Why does the loop have an explicit `{ }` scope, but not the `if` block? It would be better to be consistent about scoping braces, and have them everywhere:

```
 if (capacity > 15)
 {
     startStr = (IntPtr)Marshal.ReadInt32(address + 4);
 }
```

---

An alternative to the `StringBuilder` could be to write the bytes into a `MemoryStream`:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(length))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        stream.WriteByte(Marshal.ReadByte(startStr, i));
    }
    return new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

The nice thing with this approach is that you don't need to cast every single byte of the string into a `char`. On the other hand, you need 2 objects instead of one, and you need to cleanly `Dispose` of the stream, too - depending on the length of the string, the overhead might just not be worth it, although my guts tell me the stream could be faster... but I think you'd need to race your horses to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and all the insight, indeed I tend to wrap things around {} always but since I was pretty tired when I was doing this piece of  code I might have slept it. The length is a really good point again I'm so used to create the stringbuilder without defining a length that it was automatically that way. So in the I could probably gain some performance switching to a MemoryStream but wouldn't be some that might be worth switching over? Or it would depend mainly on the string size?

Comment: I believe for ~50 iterations it could be slower than the builder, I had a much higher number of iterations in mind... but really the only way to find out for sure is to profile it. I just suggested the stream as an *alternative*, and noted it removed the need for casting every character. I think the StringBuilder version might do just fine though. 50 iterations are completed in the blink of an eye anyway.